# Notation inconsistencies in matrix differentiation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, matrix-calculus

1.
Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let $g(z) = f(Xz)$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n,n}.$ I am interested in $\nabla_{z} g(z).$

$$\nabla_{z} g(z) = \nabla f_{Xz}(Xz) * D_{z}(Xz)$$
$$\nabla_{z} g(z) = \nabla f_{Xz}(Xz) * X$$

Now, $X \in \mathbb{R}^{nxn}$ and $\nabla f_{Xz}(Xz) \in \mathbb{R}^{n, 1}$, causing a dimension mismatch. Of course, everything works out if we swap the twp, but what about non commutativity of matrix multiplication?

2. Consider [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) for functions of vector input.
   $$x_{n+1} = x_{n} - \frac{f(x_{n})}{\nabla f(x_{n})}$$

The numerator is a real number. The denominator is a vector. How to think about this? This isn't the additive inverse is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the notation is somewhat misleading. The notation $\nabla_z f$ should mean the gradient vector $\nabla f(z)$ of $f$ at the point $z$. But what you are interested in is $\nabla_z g=\nabla g(z)$, not $\nabla_z f$. About the inconsistency, in fact inconsistency comes from regarding the gradient $\nabla f$ as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n,1}$, that is, a $n$-dimensional **column** vector. We should write 
$$\nabla f(p) = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(p),\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}(p),\ldots, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(p)\right)$$ as a **row** vector to be consistent with the chain rule of differentiation. This gives
$$
\nabla g(z) = \nabla_z [f(Xz)]=\nabla f(Xz)\cdot \frac{\partial (Xz)}{\partial z}=\nabla f(Xz)\cdot X.
$$ Note that we can right multiply $X$ since we write $\nabla f(Xz)$ as a $n$-dimensional row vector.

**EDIT**: According to @Rahul's comment, probably the way I learned to write $\nabla f$ is different from that of most people. So another way to make the notation consistent with the chain rule is to write
$$
Dg(z) = Df(Xz)\cdot X
$$ and let $Df =\text{transpose}[\nabla f] =\nabla f'$.

Comment: Doesn't this seem a bit arbitrary? It seems we choose to represent the gradient here as a row vector to suit the particular requirement of matrix multiplication. Is there some canonical way of choosing row vs. column vector to represent the gradient?

Comment: Well, it is true  that we sometimes write $\nabla f$ as a column vector. But I believe row vector notation is a standard one. This is why: consider a more general case of differentiable map $F:\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$ and its Jacobian matrix $DF$. We never write $DF$ as a $m\times n$ matrix. Note that a linear map $T:\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$ has a $n\times m$ matrix representation $A$ and it's because we adopt $T(x)=Ax$ rather than $T(x)=x'A$. So we should write $DF$ as a $n\times m$ matrix to see $DF$ as a linear approximation of $F$ at a given point. Now, $f$ is the case where$n=1$

Comment: In this regard, if we view $\nabla f$ as representing a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, we should write it as $1\times n$ row vector. Otherwise, $f(x+h) = f(x) +\nabla f(x) h +o(h)$ is non-sense. ((About $Ax$ rather than $x'A$ part, I mean we choose to multiply matrix $A$ to the left of the vector $x$, not to the right.))

Comment: The derivative of a function $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is indeed more naturally written as a row vector, for the reasons you state. But the notation $\nabla f$ always denotes the *gradient vector*, which is a column vector (equivalently, the transpose of the Jacobian). The first-order Taylor series is then expressed via an inner product, $f(x+h)=f(x)+\nabla f(x)\cdot h+o(h)$. (cc @ski)

Comment: @Rahul Umm ... honestly I didn't know that $\nabla f$ denotes column vector (and it is standard) since my multivariate calculus book (written in my first language) taught me to write $\nabla f$ as a row vector...

Comment: Interesting. $\nabla f$ has always been a column vector in my experience, but maybe it's not as universal a convention as I thought. Certainly gradient descent via $x_{k+1} = x_k - \alpha_{k+1}\nabla f(x_k)$ doesn't make sense if $x$ and $\nabla f(x)$ don't have the same shape.

Comment: @Rahul I may be missing something, but isn't the product of the gradient vector and $h$ an outer product in your Taylor series example since the gradient is a column vector?

Comment: @ski I'm using the dot product, $x\cdot y=\sum x_iy_i=x^Ty$.